# DiscardVirtualMemory Could Not Be Located (R Studio)

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, upgrade

Running Windows Server 2012, and tried to update R Studio to the latest version.  Now when I try to load R Studio I get the error:

> The procedure entry point DisardVirtualMemory could not be located in
> the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\RStudio\rstudio.exe

Googling hasn't helped to resolve this issue.